# Get custom post_type's archive URL

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

It seems like stupid question. But, I can't figure it out :(.

I need to display button at home that goes to custom post_type's archive URL (archive-{post_type}.php). How do I do that?

Comment: What sort of button, add one to a nav menu, or just a generic link? The archive URL is generally `yoursite.com/type-slug` unless you explicitly set it to something else, eg. `yoursite.com/some-other-url`..

Comment: @t31os: yup, right now, I hardcoded it like that. But, will soon change it using @Mike's code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hi **@Silent:**

Turns out there is a function in WordPress 3.1 that does exactly what you want and it is named `get_post_type_archive_link()`; here's how you'd call it *(assuming a custom post type named `'product'`):*

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('product'); ?>">Products</a>
```

Below is my prior answer before I discovered that WordPress did indeed have a function built-in for this use case.

### Prior Answer:

Unless I overlooked something in the core source code for WordPress 3.1 I think you are looking for a function like `get_archive_link()` which you might call like this *(assuming a custom post type named `'product'`):*

```
<a href="<?php echo get_archive_link('product'); ?>">Products</a>
```

And here's the source code which you can place into your theme's `function.php` file or in a `.php` file for a plugin you might be writing:

```
if (!function_exists('get_archive_link')) {
  function get_archive_link( $post_type ) {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $archive_link = false;
    if (isset($wp_post_types[$post_type])) {
      $wp_post_type = $wp_post_types[$post_type];
      if ($wp_post_type->publicly_queryable)
        if ($wp_post_type->has_archive && $wp_post_type->has_archive!==true)
          $slug = $wp_post_type->has_archive;
        else if (isset($wp_post_type->rewrite['slug']))
          $slug = $wp_post_type->rewrite['slug'];
        else
          $slug = $post_type;
      $archive_link = get_option( 'siteurl' ) . "/{$slug}/";
    }
    return apply_filters( 'archive_link', $archive_link, $post_type );
  }
}
```

I was actually working on this exact logic over the weekend although I'm not yet 100% sure the order of the logic is generically correct across all use-cases that WordPress might see although it will probably work for any specific site.

This is also a great thing to suggest be added to WordPress via **[trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org)** which I think I will do later this evening.

Comment: btw, when you submit the trac, can you please, link it here.

Comment: @silent - Yes, of course.

Comment: @Mike - I'd have wrote something similar if you hadn't.... ;) I was wondering if this is what @silent had in mind, but the mention of a button had me thinking of something else..

Comment: @t31os - I was working on the same logic this weekend for my URL routing plugin, so I had a head start. :) As for the button, you could add an answer to address that?

Comment: I'm not really sure there's anything left to cover, i think your above function covers what was asked... :)

Comment: never mind the button. It's just simple 'a' tag ;)

Comment: @silent - Turns out WordPress already had the needed function: `get_post_type_archive_link()`; I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 12):

when you register post type you can pass a string as slug with "has_archive" parameter and make sure you also set rewrite to either true or an array but not false
and then your CPT archive URL would be http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/has_archive_slug for example

if you set in your register_post_type for example:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => 'product',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => 'products', 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')
  ); 
 register_post_type('product',$args);
```

then your single url is: 
http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/product/postName
and your archive url is:
http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/products/

Comment: Hooray. I had always thought `has_archive` was a boolean, but now I know it can be given a string, so my singular custom post type `recipe` can have a plural slug `/recipes/`

Comment: I don't recall if/when they made the switch or if this was always in error, but in 2017 `'rewrite'` only accepts a boolean or array value.  Rather than the `'rewrite' => 'product',` you have listed, it should instead be `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product' ),`.